# I want to connect my Macbook Pro to my Dell Optiplex Screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, airplay

I have tried to do a direct cable connection from the Macbook Pro (Thunderbolt) to the Dell Optiplex (HDMI) cable.

Bluetooth is ON both.
I am signed into iCloud too.

Macbook Pro Display has AirPlay Display OFF and does NOT show my Optiplex screen to be able to connect.  However, on the same Macbook Pro display screen settings, under OPTIMISE FOR I can see

Built-in Display
OptiPlex 7780

I still cannot seem to view the macbook pro on my Optiplex which is the larger screen and because I have macular degeneration I would like to be able to see the macbook pro on the Dell OptiPlex.

Please help, what do I need to do please?

A very confused Silver Lady

Comment: Bluetooth + iCloud are irrelevant to connecting a display. AirPlay is usually only used to stream to another apple device (AppleTV and iPad). What are you currently seeing on the external screen? If you can see a mac background, then you have whats called "extend display" turned on, which allows for seperate spaces on the internal and external screen. Go to your settings again and under "displays" hit "display settings". You should get a column view on the left with the internal and external screen. Select the external and select "mirror" in the drop down menu next to "use as".

Comment: Hello, I do NOT get anything appearing on the Dell Optiplex as described above.  HELP

Comment: I fear remote help is quite hard in that case. Usually when you connect any external display with the correct cable (which seems the case) and you have selected the correct input on your monitor, you should see *something* at least (assuming your Mac is powered on and not in sleep). Maybe get someone you know that can help you in person with this.